# Como validar una cadena en Java?

Tags: java, string, validación

Necesito hacer este ejercicio más simple, sin usar expresiones regulares...

Enunciado:

Implemente la  función de validación  , que acepta un nombre de usuario y devuelve  verdadero  si es aceptable y  falso  si no lo es.

Un nombre de usuario es válido si cumple las siguientes reglas:

El nombre de usuario debe tener al menos 6 caracteres y no exceder los 16 caracteres.
El nombre de usuario debe contener solo letras, números y, opcionalmente, un guión (-).
El nombre de usuario debe comenzar con una letra y no debe terminar con un guión.
Por ejemplo,  Username.validate ("Mike Standish"); devolvería  falso  porque contiene un espacio.

Hasta ahora mi idea es esta:

```
public static boolean validar(String userName){

       boolean estado = false;
       Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("/^[a-z0-9_-]{6,16}$/");
       Matcher mat = pat.matcher(userName);

              if(mat.matches()){

                     System.out.println("Cadena Valida");
                     estado=true;
              }
              else{
                     System.out.println("Cadena Invalida");
                     estado=false;
             }
             return estado;
             }
public static void main(String []args){

System.out.println("Mike Standish"); //Cadena invalida
System.out.println("Mike-Standish"); //Cadena valida
```

Comment: Puede hacer validaciones por cada punto. ej: `if(user.length < 6 || user.length() > 15) return false;` y posterior otro `if` para la siguiente validación... y así hasta finalizar las validaciones

Comment: Hola, considero que con expresiones regulares, para lo que necesitas es la forma mas simple. Ya que de otra forma es se dice en el comentario anterior. realizando ifs. usando length, startsWitch, indexOf o contains y subString.

Comment: Las expresiones regulares son tus mejores aliados en este tema. Escribir un codigo para esto seria engorroso, largo y poco optimo.

Comment: No entiendo. Dices que no puedes usar expresiones regulares, pero en tu código no usas otra cosa... Como te ha comentado @isaac, dada que no puedas hacer con un if para cada caso a comprobar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como indica un comentario, dices que el enunciado te restringe de usar regex pero tu idea es usarlo, lo cual no dejas muy claro como se debería hacer, también tu idea de que la ultima cadena debería ser validada esta mal, en tu regex no indicas que deba contener mayúsculas, con lo cual no te lo aceptara. En todo caso te dejo dos maneras cercanas de hacerlo y de ahí tu lo modificas a tu gusto. Siendo obvio que las expresiones regulares al menos son mas limpios es la primera opción que indico.

```
    public static boolean validar(String userName){

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,16}$");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(userName);

        return mat.matches();
    }

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String user = br.readLine();

        System.out.println(validar("Mike Standish")); //Cadena invalida
        System.out.println(validar("mik3-standish")); //Cadena valida
        System.out.println(validar("Mike-Standish")); //Cadena valida
        System.out.println(validar("M1k-S")); //Cadena invalida
```

Pero en caso de que quieras hacerlo a la pura de comprobación, este caso te puede ser útil.

```
        String specialChars = "~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+\\|[{]};:'\",<.>/?";
        boolean specialchar = false;
        boolean numero = false;
        if (user.length() > 6 && user.length() < 15 ){
            for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
                if (specialChars.contains(String.valueOf(user.charAt(i)))) {
                    specialchar = true;
                } else if (Character.isDigit(Integer.valueOf(user.charAt(i)))) {
                    numero = true;
                }
            }
            if (specialchar && numero) {
                System.out.println("El " + user + " es valido");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No es valido");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Como indique antes debido a que no indicas si es necesario con o sin mayúsculas deberás agregarlo o modificarlo a tu gusto. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias @ICodeForCaffeine, tu explicación y tu código me fueron de gran ayuda :)